# Does django core pagination retrieve all data first?

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-1.5

I am using django 1.5. I need to split pages to data. I read docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/pagination/#example). I am not sure about whether it retrieves all data first or not. Since I have a large table, it should be better to using something like 'limit'. Thanks.

**EDIT**

I am using queryset in ModelManager.

example:

```
class KeywordManager(models.Manager):
    def currentkeyword(self, kw, bd, ed):
         wholeres = super(KeywordManager, self).get_query_set() \
                .values("sc", "begindate", "enddate") \
                .filter(keyword=kw, begindate__gte=bd, enddate__lte=ed) \
                .order_by('enddate')

        return wholeres
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a `queryset` is a lazy object, and django will retrieve the data as soon you request it, but if you dont, django won't hit the DB. If you use over a queryset any list methods as `len()`, you will evaluate all the queryset and forcing django to retrieve all the data.

If you pass a `queryset` to the Paginator, it would not retrieve all the data, because, as docs says, if you pass a queryset, it will use .count() methods avoiding converting the `queryset` into a list and the use of `len()` method.

Comment: I have added **EDIT**. If I using p = Paginator(KeywordMdl.keywordmgr.currentkeyword(...), 10), the Paginator will reterive 10 rows from database every time for page changing, right? @levi

Answer (score 0):

If your data is not coming from the database, then yes - Paginator will have to load all the information first in order to determine how to "split" it.

If you're not and you're simply interacting with the database with Django's auto-generated SQL, then the Paginator performs a query to determine the number of items in the database (i.e. an SQL `COUNT()`) and uses the value you supplied to determine how many pages to generate. Example: `count()` returns 43, and you want pages of 10 results - the number of pages generated is equivalent to: `43 % 10 + 1 = 5`